# How to fire an Event on node publish on Drupal 8

Tags: 8, nodes, event-subscribers

I am trying to figure out how to fire an event when a node type gets published so I can set up a listener to listen to that event.

- Can someone explain what is the best practice and how to fire an event when a Node gets published?
- Do I need to listen to `EntityTypeEvents::UPDATE` and check it there?